# In Linux, how do I get man pages for C functions rather than for bash commands?

Tags: c, linux, manpage

In Linux, how do I get the man pages for C functions rather than shell commands?

For example, when I type `man bind` I get the manual page for the shell command `bind` and not the man page for socket binding C function.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
man 2 bind
```

You need a result from a different section of the manual! Man searches various sections for the information you want. As devnull lists below, the number indicates which section to search.

Incidentally, `bind` is a system call, not a C library function. System calls (kernel calls) are in section 2 of the manual, library functions are in section 3.

`man man` will tell you how to use the man command!

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that system calls are in the (2) section, and library functions in the (3) section. I.e. `man 3 printf` for printf().

Comment: I've been using Unix for over ten years and wasn't aware of this (always fell back to Internet searches).  I would type something like man `sleep\(3\)` and give up!  I think users would be more likely to reach their desired destination if the man pages read "SEE ALSO `man 3 sleep`".

Answer (score 43):

Saying `man man` would tell you:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>    man ... [[section] page ...] ...
> ```
>
> ```
>    The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the
>    types of pages they contain.
>
>    1   Executable programs or shell commands
>    2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>    3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>    4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>    5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>    6   Games
>    7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
>        man(7), groff(7)
>    8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
>    9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
> ```

For example, `man 1 printf` would show the manual for the `printf` shell utility, while `man 3 printf` would show the manual for `printf()` in libc.

(When in doubt, say `man -k foobar`.  It will provide a list of man pages with `foobar` as the regex.)

Comment: I've been using man for a bit now, but somehow never tried to do `man man`.... Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. For me, `man 3 printf` returns `No manual entry for printf in section 3`

Comment: After installing 'man-pages', 'man 3 printf' shows correct info.